# synchronized, not always true?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Does the synchronized block always works fine? I am confused now! Am I wrong when using synchronized keyword? 
The code snippet is as following:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new MyThread().start();
        }
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    // no atomic
    private static Integer count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (count) {
            //synchronized (this) {

                if (count > 100)
                    break;

                count++;
                System.out.println("ThreadId:" + currentThread().getId() + ","
                        + "inc MyThread.count to : " + count);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
ThreadId:10,inc MyThread.count to : 2
ThreadId:9,inc MyThread.count to : 2
ThreadId:9,inc MyThread.count to : 4
ThreadId:9,inc MyThread.count to : 5
ThreadId:9,inc MyThread.count to : 6
....
```

I don't know why Thread 10 and 9 output the same value.

Answer (score 9):

You are doing absolutely the wrong thing. First, you synchronize on the updated field. The synchronization will be kept on the object which was in the `count` variable upon synchronization block entry, but you modify it later. So if the second thread is started when first one already incremented a value, then first will be synchronized on `Integer.valueOf(0)` and second on `Integer.valueOf(1)` and they will not wait for each other.

The second problem is that you synchronizing on the `Integer` which is cached for small values and may be reused in completely different part of program, so you may end up waiting for something completely unrelated.

Note that synchronization on `this` will not help either as `this` is the `MyThread` object which is different in every thread.

You can fix your code synchronizing on some shared object which does not change through the execution. It's better to create a special lock object for this purpose:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    // no atomic
    private static Integer count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response very much !

Comment: Now I can understand why the code works unexpected! Thanks for your help!

Comment: synchronized(this Integer variable) should work fine, but we shouldn't do that, we'd better use a business irrelevant variable, just as you mentioned, private static Object lock = new Object(). Am I right?

Comment: @zhangjie You are partly right:  There is nothing wrong with synchronizing on an `Integer` variable except that, really, there is no such thing as synchronizing on a _variable_.  You synchronize on an _object_, and in this case, the mistake is that each thread potentially synchronizes on a _different_ object because `count++` updates `count` to refer to a different `Integer` instance each time.